# Unexpected token ) javascript

Tags: javascript

My program should create a team which contains 9 players.  I think I did all of that correctly.  I think the issue is within the show_teams() function.  It says I have an unexpected token ).  It says it is located at the button show_teams(), but I think it is really contained in the actual method.

I posted my code over here.
PROPER LINK I apologize. 
http://pastebin.com/t7KbgmPD

I'm really not sure what I have done wrong.  I'm new to outputting things, but I just wrote up all the other code and I do not believe there are any mistakes in there.

Thanks

I updated the code with fixes.  Still having bad issues. I think I implemented this wrong and I'll just start over.

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes? i.e. \' instead of '

Comment: What's this? `this.players() = teamPlayers();` Also, please consider using semicolons and explicit braces to indicate blocks.

Comment: @leonm: He isn't. He linked to the wrong part of Pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 98

```
for (var p = 0; p < teams[i].players.lenth; p++) {
```

There is a typo - `lenth` should be `length`

On line 140, - A missing closing paranthesis

`createTeam(this.form.name.value)`

To detect javascript errors etc, you can validate using an online tool like [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Comment: thank you, is there an editor that would spot things like this out?

Comment: yes.. You could us jsfiddle.net - it is pretty good. Also there are bunch of online javascript validators

Comment: are you still facing issues?

Comment: Yeah, but I guess I'm confused on how to create objects and use them. Thank you for your concern.  Sometime the people on here are not really that friendly.  lol

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/object.shtml this is a good tutorial.

Comment: I edited the pastebin it is saying that my batA is not defined, but I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was pastbin. However:

```
    <input type="button"
       onclick="createTeam(this.form.name.value"
       value="Create Team"
    />
```

Add a parenthesis to that call in the `onclick` and you should be fine.

Comment: idk why postbit put the \, but they are not there I use no \

Comment: There is no `\\`. He linked to the 'embed Pastebin JavaScript' code rather than the code *in* the paste.

Comment: @Brad Christie   on line 71 it is saying pname is not defined?

Comment: @KirsKringle: Yea, you have a lot going on here. `pname` should probably be `name` to match the incoming argument. Then `batA` is undefined (not sure where that's coming from). karthikr found another error, and I'm sure there are others.